# Cant make tool bar view disappear/hide

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created a tool bar but now when I want to logout and navigate to login page, the tool bar will not disappear

This is my main View:

```
var body: some View{
        
        VStack(spacing: 0){
    
            ZStack{
                switch selectedIndex{
                case 0:
                    MeniuListView()
                default:
                    ProfileShopView()
                }
                
            }
            
            
            Divider()
            HStack{ //This HStack will always be on
                ForEach(0..<2, id: \.self){number in
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedIndex=number

                    }, label: {
                        VStack(spacing: 3){
                        if number == 2{
                            Image(systemName: icons[number])
                                .font(.system(size: 25,
                                             weight: .regular,
                                             design: .default))
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                        
                    })
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my ProfileShopView() Where i have the logout button and where I redirect to the login page:

```
 var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
        
        VStack{
            
                Form{
                  {
                        TextField("Name", value: $restaurantMobile, formatter: NumberFormatter())
                    }
                   {
                        TextField("Name2", value: $price, formatter: NumberFormatter()).keyboardType(UIKeyboardType.decimalPad)
                    }
                  }
                
            NavigationLink(destination: LoginView().navigationBarHidden(true), tag: 1, selection: $goToNextScreen)
                {
                    EmptyView()
                    //How to close all the other views???
                }
                Button(action: {
                    goToNextScreen=1
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isLogin")
                }
            }
```

The problem is that the redirect happens but the toolbar its still active, like this:
So basically the first tool bar will never close. How can I close it or empty it?

[image]

How I can avoid this and close the toolbar on the logout?
Can I redirect to a new view and close all the others active views somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

- `tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false`
- or `.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)`(iOS 16+)
  ?

Comment: I do not have a tabBarController at all, the only code that I user to generate the tab bar its up on the question